# How to pull data from own Flask JSON route endpoint using Axios

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, server, axios

I would like to save JSON data into a variable using Axios in Javascript. The route that produces the JSON endpoint is my own servers route `http://123.4.5.6:7890/json`. This works successfully with the following function:

```
async function getClasses() {
    const res = await axios.get('http://123.4.5.6:7890/json');
}
```

However, I figure this won't work with someone else's server when they pull up my project, so what line of code would go into the `http://` spot? My mentor recomended using 'http://localhost:5000/json' however this error occurs when I tried this.

[image]

Here is the python code for my json route:

```
@app.route('/json')
def display_json():
    """view/signup for available yoga classes using API"""

    serialized_classes = [c.serialize() for c in Classes.query.all()]

    return jsonify(serialized_classes)
```

When I go to the http://123.4.5.6:7890/json route in my browser. JSON does successfully appear in the browser. Thanks, and any help is appreciated

Comment: In your server code, how did you setup routing for your endpoint? Do you run endpoint on your localhost and it is working?

Comment: Edited my code to include my Python flask code for the route. I can provide more code as well, since this doesn't show how my class models are set up

Comment: my endpoint does work successfully if I just include my own server's route

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a CORS issue, you can use the below code to solve this issue.

```
var config = {
    headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}
};

async function getClasses() {
    const res = await axios.get('http://123.4.5.6:7890/json', config);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

on your app.py or main.py file

```
from flask_cors import CORS
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
```

Comment: ran into an import error after trying this. How would I install this in a command line? would this work? pip install -U flask-cors

Comment: pip install flask_cors